# Oracle SQL use variable partition name

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

I run a daily report that has to query another table which is updated separately. Due to the high volume of records in the source table (8M+ per day) each day is stored in it's own partition. The partition has a standard format as `P ... 4 digit year ... 2 digit month ... 2 digit date`, so yesterday's partition is `P20140907`.

At the moment I use this expression, but have to manually change the name of the partition each day:

```
select * from <source_table> partition (P20140907) where ....
```

By using `sysdate`, `toChar` and `Concat` I have created another table called `P_NAME2` that will automatically generate and update a string value as the name of the partition that I need to read. Now I need to update my main query so it does this:

```
select * from <source_table> partition (<string from P_NAME2>) where ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd pop back to share how I solved this in the end. The source database has a habit of leaking dates across partitions which is why queries for one day were going outside a single partition. I can't affect this, just work around it ...

```
begin    
execute immediate 
'create table LL_TEST as
select *
from SCHEMA.TABLE Partition(P'||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')||')
where COLUMN_A=''Something''
and COLUMN_B=''Something Else''
';
end
;
```

Using the PL/SQL script I create the partition name with `TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')` and concatenate the rest of the query around it.

Note that the values you are searching for in the where clause require double apostrophes so to send `'Something'` to the query you need `''Something''` in the script.

It may not be pretty, but it works on the database that I have to use.

Answer (score 1):

You are working too hard. Oracle already does all these things for you. If you query the table using the correct date range oracle will perform the operation only on the relevant partitions - this is called **pruning** .

I suggest reading the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_avail.htm#BABCDHIF) on that.

If you'r still skeptic, Query `all_tab_partitions.HIGH_VALUE` to get each partitions high value (the table you created ... ).

Comment: If I try to select using a date range the processing load and run times are much higher as it still scans the whole database to find the date limits. Working by partition is much more efficient. The source table is already pre-partitioned up to 2030 with future dates empty. Picking the highest partition won't find anything. (The source table isn't mine)

Comment: @CJC - haki's query shows you the highest value allowed in each partition, not the highest partition. Are your stats up-to-date? Is your `where` clause forcing an implicit data conversion that is stopping the pruning/indexing being applied properly (e.g. comparing to a string instead of a date)?